# byte array permute SSE optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, sse, simd

I would like to translate this code using SSE intrinsics.
I found the `pshufb` SSSE3 instruction and similar `__builtin_ia32_pshufb128(v128i, v128i)` GCC intrinsic that may possibly be used with this code.
The code permutes a vector of bytes `s` by index `k` via swapping bytes in the array with specific way.

```
void permutation(int k, std::vector<char> & s) 
{
  for(size_t j = 1; j < s.size(); ++j) 
  {
      std::swap(s[k % (j + 1)], s[j]); 
      k = k / (j + 1);
  }
}
```

I spent a good hour thinking how to translate the code to `pshufb`. Is it possible to permute 16-bytes with single `pshufb` or does it require multiple instructions? Good enough solution would permute just 16 bytes at time.

EDIT: Further context of the problem: I'm iterating over all possible permutations of `s`. Computing ahead `k = 0, 1, 2,...` multiple results for same `s` is ok. However I need to reproduce the `k`-th permutation later preferably as O(1) operation.

Comment: What is the range of possible values of `k` ? Also what is the typical size of `s` ?

Comment: This link should provide all you want to know:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531427(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This is a rather curious permutation.  For all `j` such that `j`! > `k`, this will just swap `s[j]` with `s[0]`, which will insert just shuffle the original `s[j]` up by one, and leave the last one in `s[0]`.

Comment: Even if you are using 64-bit int's (unlikely), that will be true for all `j` > 20.  For 32-bit ints, it will be true for all `j` > 12.  If you are permuting vectors greater than that, you probably want to break when k == 0, and use memmove for the remaining slide.  If you are permutting vectors less than that, I have a hard time believing this is your performance bottleneck.

Comment: Typical size of `s` would be multiple of 16-bytes. Solution just for 16 bytes is okay. `k` index is incremented in fairly tight loop until the permuted result matches certain criteria or `k` would overflow. I also limit by condition how big `k` can get.

Comment: Do you try to iterate over all possible permutations of size `|s|` ? I would recommend using `std::next_permutation`, it does not use division, which is a very slow operation.

Comment: Regarding vectorization: is it allowed to process several consecutive values of `k` (e.g. k = 24, 25, 26, ..., 29) at once ? Do you use same string `s` for different `k` ? Is it OK to precalculate and store some lookup data?

Comment: See question again. I explained more how I use the `permutation()`.

Comment: You can process 16 strings at once and store all 16 values of `s[j]` (for single value of j) in a single `__m128i` register. In such transposed layout you can simply swap registers like you usually swap bytes (if swap indices are the same).
Then you can probably achieve better performance. But you have to do all your checks in this transposed layout, because transposing data back to "string-per-register" layout is very costly.

Comment: Perhaps rename the question to "Generate all permutations of byte array with SSE", if you see it appropriate ?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Single call

Notice that you can write down the number `k` in positional notation system with [mixed radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix), so that each digit in this representation would define indices of swapped elements for several consecutive values of `j`.

For example, for strings of length 12 you can write any `k` as a three-digit number with bases:

```
720 = 1*2*3*4*5*6  (0-th digit, lowest value)
504 = 7*8*9        (1-th digit)
1320 = 10*11*12    (2-th digit, highest value)
```

Now you can precompute for each position and for each value of digit in this position the cumulative permutation of all your elements, and save it in a lookup table. Then you would be able to do several swaps by single instruction.

Here is a sample (precomputation would be the hardest part):

```
//to be precomputed:
__m128i mask0[ 720];
__m128i mask1[ 504];
__m128i mask2[1320];

__m128i permutation(int k, __m128i s) {
    s = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, mask0[k %  720]); k /=  720;  //j = [1..5]
    s = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, mask1[k %  504]); k /=  504;  //j = [6..8]
    s = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, mask2[k       ]);             //j = [9..11]
    return s;
}
```

You can vary the decomposition into bases in order to balance between number of steps and size of lookup table.

**Note:** division operation is very slow. Use only divisions by compile-time constants, then the optimizer would transform them into multiplications. Check the generated assembly to make sure that no division instructions are there.

### Many calls

Unfortunately, index calculations would still eat most of the time with suggested solution, see [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/fPorXX). This overhead can be significantly reduced if you process several consecutive values of `k` at once.

The simplest approach to optimize the solution would be: iterate over digits of `k` separately instead of doing a single loop over `k`. Then index calculations become unnecessary. Also, you can reuse partially computed results.

```
__m128i s;// = ???
for (int k0 = 0; k0 <  720; k0++) {
    __m128i s0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, mask0[k0]);
    for (int k1 = 0; k1 <  504; k1++) {
        __m128i s1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s0, mask1[k1]);
        for (int k2 = 0; k2 < 1320; k2+=4) {
            //for k = (((k2+0) * BASE1) + k1) * BASE0 + k0:
            __m128i sx0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s1, mask2[k2+0]);
            //for k = (((k2+1) * BASE1) + k1) * BASE0 + k0:
            __m128i sx1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s1, mask2[k2+1]);
            //for k = (((k2+2) * BASE1) + k1) * BASE0 + k0:
            __m128i sx2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s1, mask2[k2+2]);
            //for k = (((k2+3) * BASE1) + k1) * BASE0 + k0:
            __m128i sx3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s1, mask2[k2+3]);

            // ... check four strings: sx0, sx1, sx2, sx3
        }
    }
}
```

This way you need to do one shuffle per each permutation on average (see [assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/LwULIH)), which seems close to perfect.

### Code and results

Here is the [full working code](http://pastebin.com/n5U0wtL9) of all solutions.

Note that generation of the lookup tables is not trivial to fully explain, and the corresponding code is rather large (and filled with nasty details).

The benchmark run on *Intel Core 2 Duo E4700 Allendale (2600MHz)* gives results:

```
2.605 s: original code         (k < 12739451)
0.125 s: single-call fast code (k < 12739451)
4.822 s: single-call fast code (k < 479001600)
0.749 s: many-call fast code   (k < 479001600)
```

So the single-call version is about **20** times faster than the original code, and the many-call version is about **6.5** times faster than the single-call version.

Comment: Nice analysis !

Comment: Very nice indeed. :) I'm bit baffled how to fill the lookup arrays, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Nice answer! One thing, maybe instead of shuffling `s` over and over again, one could save the result of the three shuffles into three different variables and then join the results (ORs will do, shuffles can zero elements). This could break the long dependency chain and execute faster.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Not really, because each shuffle is dependent on the result of the previous one. I guess it would be better to partially unroll the outer loop by `k` (given that iterations by `k` do not depend on each other).

Comment: My point was to *not* make the shuffles depend on each other.

Comment: @stgatilov: the many calls asm is looking fantastic. I never expected to get this much help. Thanks. Can I still get `k` for `sx0`..`sx3` so that I can reproduce the `k`-th result with single call version? If you could explain bit how to begin generating the lookup tables or what `mask0[0]` ... `mask0[719]` bits look like, I'll accept your answer. :-)

Comment: @JATothrim: now answer contains a link to full working code with generation of lookup tables included. Also added benchmark results. You can always get `k` as `k0 + k1 * BASE0 + k2 * BASE0*BASE1` in the many-call version (four versions of `sx` are obtained from four consecutive values of `k2`, that's simply 4x loop unrolling).

Comment: Hooray! I managed to generate the lookup tables. (trial + a lot of coffee) see: [link](http://pastebin.com/DWUG3iWk) Funny thing is that the table gen itself needs to shuffle the mask bytes that then shuffle the data bytes...